# Registration, first registration returns row exists?

Tags: php, sql, registration

I have developed a registration system that sends an activation code via email.
If that username already exists, it returns an error "Username already exists".

When I don't have any users in the database, the first username I register returns "Username already exists!" and automatically inserts the user into the database.

But when I try again & already have a user in my db, it works perfectly.

What is the problem there?

Register method:

```
   /**
    * Public Method Register
    *
    * Registers the user to the system, checking for errors.
    * If error was found, it will throw new exception.
    *
    * @parm username The username the user posted.
    * @parm password The password the user posted.
    * @parm repassword The validated password the user posted.
    * @parm email The email the user posted.
    * @parm reemail The validated email the user posted.
    * @parm day The day the user posted (for date of birth).
    * @parm month The month the user posted (for date of birth).
    * @parm year The year the user posted (for date of birth).
    *
    * @return Return true means everything is correct, register successfully.
    **/

    public function register($username, $password, $repassword, $email, $reemail, $day, $month, $year)
    {

        // Check if passwords matching.
        if ($password != $repassword)
        {
            throw new exception ("Passwords does not match.");
        }
        // Check if emails matching.
        else if ($email != $reemail)
        {
            throw new exception ("Emails does not match.");
        }

        //Query to check if username is taken.
        $this->user = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = :name");
        $this->user->execute(array(":name" => $username));

        //Query to check if email is taken.
        $this->email = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = :email");
        $this->email->execute(array(":email" => $email));                      

        // Checking if username is taken using the query.
        if ($this->user->rowCount())
        {
            throw new exception ("That username is already in use!");
        }
        // Checking if email is taken using the query.                 
        else if ($this->email->rowCount())
        {
            throw new exception ("Email is already in use");
        }
        // Checking if birth of date is valid.
        else if ($day > 31 || $month > 12 || $year > date('Y') || $year < 1925)
        {
            throw new exception ("Invalid Birth of date");
        }
        //checking if password is more than 5 characters long.
        else if (strlen($password) < 5)
        {
            throw new exception ("Password is too short");
        }
        else
        {
            // The main insert query
            $this->insert = $this->pdo->prepare
            ("
                INSERT INTO users
                (user_name, user_password, user_email, user_birth)
                VALUES
                (:username, :password, :email, :birth)
            "); 

            // Everything is fine, insert data.

            $this->insert->execute(array
            (
                ":username" => $username,
                ":password" => $password,
                ":email" => $email,
                ":birth" => $day.'/'.$month.'/'.$year
            ));

            //Send verification

            $this->sendVerification($username, $email);
            //Finished processing, return true.
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Database build:

```
Field   Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
    user_name   varchar(100)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None                                
    user_password   varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None                                
    user_email  varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None                                
    user_id int(100)            No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT                          
    is_admin    int(1)          No  None                                
    is_mod  int(1)          No  None                                
    user_avatar varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None                                
    user_ip varchar(100)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None                                
    user_birth  varchar(100)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None                                
    user_registration_date  varchar(100)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None                                
    user_theme_downloads    int(100)            No  None                                
    user_theme_pruchases    int(100)            No  None                                
    is_verified int(1)          No  0                               
    lastLogin   timestamp       on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Reigstration call:

```
                try
                {
                    $users->register($_POST['name'], $_POST['pass'], $_POST['pass2'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['email2'], $_POST['day'], $_POST['month'], $_POST['year']);
                    $_SESSION['registered'] = $_POST['email'];
                }
                catch (exception $e)
                {
                    $error = '<div class="alert-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</div>';
                }
```

***More information:***

Email sending fails with the following error:

```
13.05.17 01:28:03 : Must issue a STARTTLS command first. g7sm13929808eew.15 - gsmtp<EOL>
13.05.17 01:32:28 : Must issue a STARTTLS command first. g7sm13954936eew.15 - gsmtp<EOL>
13.05.17 01:56:20 : Must issue a STARTTLS command first. c42sm14092691eeb.10 - gsmtp<EOL>
13.05.17 16:33:46 : Socket Error # 11004<EOL>
13.05.17 21:44:19 : Must issue a STARTTLS command first. y10sm20698432eev.3 - gsmtp<EOL>
```

Using a Gmail account, it used to work 2 weeks ago.

Verification method:

```
    /**
    * Private Method sendVerification
    *
    * Sends the account a verification ID to his email
    * Generates verification ID string using SHA512
    * using the static method for our random string
    * generation.
    *
    * @parm username The username public function register
    * requested.
    * @parm email The email public function register requested
    **/

    private function sendVerification($username, $email)
    {
        $salt = self::generateSalt($email, $username);

        $this->check = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where user_name = :username AND user_email = :email");
        $this->check->execute(array
        (
            ":username" => $username,
            ":email" => $email
        ));

        if ($this->check->rowCount())
        {
            $this->get = $this->check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $this->insert = $this->pdo->prepare
            ("
                INSERT INTO account_verifications
                (user_id, generated_code, date, time)
                VALUES
                (:id, :code, CURDATE(), CURTIME())
            ");
            $generatedCode = self::generateCode($salt);
            $this->insert->execute(array
            (
                ":id" => $this->get['user_id'],
                ":code" => $generatedCode
            ));

            $this->check = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM account_verifications WHERE user_id = :id AND generated_code = :code");
            $this->check->execute(array
            (
                ":id" => $this->get['user_id'],
                ":code" => $generatedCode
            ));

            if ($this->check->rowCount())
            {
                $this->get = $this->check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                mail
                (
                    $email,
                    'Driptone - Activate your account',
                    'Hello '.$username.'. you must activate your account before
                    you can start using your account.
                    You can activate your account by clicking on the following link:
                    http://localhost/drip/activate.php?u='.$this->get['user_id'].'&a='.$this->get['generated_code'].'
                    Thank you,
                    Driptone.',
                    'From: noreply@driptone.com'
                );
            }
            else
            {
                throw new exception ("sHIT Happens!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new exception ("An error has occured!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code can't return `Username already exists` - do you mean it returns `That username is already in use`?

Comment: How you are calling register function?

Comment: It throws a new exception with string "Username already exists" if row count with the same username.

Comment: @user2391753 - no, it throws an exception with the string `That username is already in use!` in that case. If you're seeing the string `Username already exists`, then you might want to add the code that returns that, because that string does not exist in the code you've added here.

Comment: Exactly, it returns 'That username is already in use!', my fault, sorry. + It's in the div class named alert-danger.

Comment: Added more possibly useful information.

Answer (score 1):

From the manual:

```
PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE,
INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.


If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT
statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement.
However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be
relied on for portable applications.
```

Since you can't rely on it for a select statement, I would use

```
$this->check = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users where user_name = :username AND user_email = :email");
```

and then check the value returned, rather than using a function that may or may not do what you think it should do.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem.

If I don't have any rows, I must use

```
$this->users->rowCount() == 1
```

Because rowCount returns a string.

This have fixed my issue, thanks everyone.

Comment: Read Dave's answer and rethink! (and it returns a number - not a string)